# Nested Case Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I am writing a case statement to fetch results every 2 hours. I need to sum all the results but exclude the following timestamps : 2016-01-08 00:00:00.000 (all the ones that have basically no timestamp in the database.

My query looks like this:

```
select 

sum(
    CASE WHEN (End_Trailer_Break >= dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, -10, GETDATE())), 0)  and End_Trailer_Break < dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0,  DATEADD(HOUR, -8, GETDATE())), 0))
       THEN convert(int,replace (Tonnage, ',',''))
       ELSE 0 END
    ) AS 'Tonnage'  

from pm_inbound
```

I think I need to add this somewhere as a nested case statement to exclude the 00:00 timestamps:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(5),DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, End_Trailer_Break), 0) ,8),'00:00','')
```

Thank you

Comment: Why a case?  Just use  a where clause to exclude those.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you!